# Jsch - System in, out and er without redirection?

Tags: java, swing, jsch, system.in

I am in the process of playing with [Jcrafts JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) Library to build a Terminal application.

It works fine and does what it says, however I have to redirect System out, in and err to various swing components for it work in a GUI application.

I have noticed with System.in redirection it relies on a keypress to submit the text to System.in, this is fine until you need to use CRTL keys for example. Also up arrow for previous commands.

**Class for System.in redirection and KeyListener for submission**

```
public class TextAreaStream extends InputStream implements KeyListener {

    private JTextArea ta;
    private String str = null;
    private int pos = 0;

    public TextAreaStream(JTextArea jtf) {
        ta = jtf;
    }

    //gets triggered everytime that "Enter" is pressed on the textfield
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_ENTER)
        {
        str = ta.getText() + "\n";
        pos = 0;
        ta.setText("");
        synchronized (this) {
             this.notifyAll();
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() {
        if(str != null && pos == str.length()){
            str =null;
            return java.io.StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF;
        }
        while (str == null || pos >= str.length()) {
            try {

                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return str.charAt(pos++);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

My question is "Is there a way to have System.in recognize up arrows and CRTL- commands with JSch, or is there a better way of displaying a console screen in a Java Swing application?"

**Implentation**

```
//System input redirection from TextArea
        TextAreaStream ts = new TextAreaStream(textAreaInput);
        textAreaInput.addKeyListener(ts);
        System.setIn(ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no possible way to get one single character on Java console. You will be fine, if it´s ok to read a whole line. But a single character is impossible. Two things that you can do:

1. Simulate a console which is built via a Java GUI and set a KeyStroke Listener to it.
2. Get the raw data Input from the stream by using JNI. But this seems to be very complex.

Comment: I would have thought that I could pass a single character using KeyPressed or KeyTyped methods? Also, your option one is what I have already done, unless you have a better way of achieving this?

Comment: The point is, that there simply are no keypressed methods exists. That means, that you can read a whole line or nothing. It´s not implemented in Java yet. Maybe Oracle saw no need for doing this. So, you need to implement it at your own.

Comment: Hmm. Thats strange as they are Keypress and KeyTyped methods if the KeyListener class.